# Customization censored in textBox

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I have problem, which consists in aesthetic sense, correctly - There is textBox to which i apply true condition of UseSystemPasswordChar.. It's work! But i get bold points. Try to change font size - decreases textbox's field. Below is the code (although why is it here?). Can anyone help, thank you in advance)

```
public partial class frmRegistr : Form
    {
        public frmRegistr()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        int counter = 0;
        int a = 0;
        string b;
        private void frmRegistr_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            b = label1.Text;
            a = b.Length;
            label1.Text = "";
            timer1.Start();

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (counter < a)
            {
                
                counter++;
                label1.Text = b.Substring(0, counter);
            }
            else
            {
                
                timer1.Stop();
            }

           
        }

        private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer3.Start();
        }

        private void label4_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //if this.MouseLeave
            label4.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(154)))), ((int)(((byte)(181)))), ((int)(((byte)(101)))));
        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Opacity == 1)
            {
                timer2.Stop();
            }

            Opacity += .2;

        }

        private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Opacity <= 0)
            {
                this.Close();
            }

            Opacity -= .2;
        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             
            textBox2.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the [PasswordChar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar)? Why are you setting `UseSystemPasswordChar = true` in the `TextChanged` event? You usually set that property once. But it appears you don't want to use the default System Password Char... -- Could you rephrase *I have problem, which consists in aesthetic sense, correctly*, it's not exactly clear what that means.

Comment: Clearly you don't have to show all code, you only have to show the relevant parts

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define your own password character, use property [TextBox.PasswordChar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar?view=net-5.0). If you want this in a certain font, use [Control.Font](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.font?view=net-5.0)

As you only have to do this once, do this in the constructor:

```
public MyForm : Form
{
    InitializeComponents(),
    this.textBox1.PasswordChar = '_';
    this.textBox11.Font = new Font(...)
};
```

You can also decide to do this using the visual studio designer.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup this in VisualStudio designer, but this is code:

```
textBox1.PasswordChar = '*';
//* = password character
```